# Как перевести число в строку на человеческом языке?

Tags: javascript, строки

Как перевести число в строку на натуральном языке, чтобы, например, из `123` получилась строка «сто двадцать три»?

Желательно без использования `array()`.

Comment: @David Kern, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Думаю подразумевается "Написать число строкой"

123 = "сто двадцать три"

Comment: спасибо я уже написал код виды рад если помогите усовершенствовать  код .

http://codepen.io/DavidKern/pen/pvLobM

проблема в том когда набираю номер 316234 допустить то он не  пишет шестнадцать а пишет тристо один шесть я попытался вставить if но тогда на других числах появились проблемы . Благодарю за помощь :)

Comment: нужно кодировать правила языка. На CodePen у вас иддиш, я его не знаю. На русском будет, возможно, другая логика: своё слово для тысяч, сот, десятков >= 2, свои названия для чисел от 11 до 19. И хорошо, если не нужны падежи : ) Нашёлся [велосипед](http://javascript.ru/blog/exru/perevod-chisla-tekst) для русского языка.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Машина не знает чему сопоставлять числа

Comment: пожалуйста :))))))))
http://codepen.io/DavidKern/pen/pvLobM